# Matplotlib: Plot a function with multiple defintions

Tags: matplotlib, plot

How do I plot e.g. a function f(x) = x for 0 < x < 1 and f(x) = 1 for x >= 1?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Okay, I have thought for a while and found a solution for the given function, but I'd really like to find a more generic solution. Maybe like f=f1+f2+...fn, where fi is the function in domain i and then plot f alltogehter.

f = 0.5*(1*(1-np.sign(1-x))+x*(1-np.sign(x-1)))

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If you show what you have tried and at what point it fails it will probably be much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib doesn't care where your data comes from: you can either make lists from two different functions and combine them, or call a function with a conditional in it.  The most mathematically appealing choice is probably

```
def f(x):
  return 1 if x>=1 else 0 if x>0 else ...
```

Of course, if you care only about *x*>0, your function can be computed just as `x>=1`, which can be used as a number already.